# magento site error

Tags: magento

I just moved my magento site to another server and i am getting this error at the footer area

*Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/bzd088/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 160' in /home/bzd088/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245 Stack trace: #0 /home/bzd088/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(160): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/bzd088/pu...', 160, Array) #1 /home/bzd088/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(127): Varien_Autoload->_saveCollectedStat() #2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->__destruct() #3 {main} thrown in /home/bzd088/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245*

Comment: Are you 100% certain that everything has been moved, and permissions set?

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the compilation mode.  You probably need to re-run this process.

To disable compilation mode: http://kb.magenting.com/content/24/81/en/disable-magento-compiler.html

Answer (score 0):

File permission issue

Please recheck file permission of all directory on root